# External hard disk not mounting

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk, mount

I have a WD My Passport Ultra Hard Disk. I am trying to use it on El Capitan.

Its not showing up in the Finder.

When I open Disk Utility, it just keeps loading forever and does not show any information at all.

I tried rebooting the system, that didnt work.

Then I went to the Terminal. The disk is showing up there:

```
Amits-MacBook-Pro:~ amit1235813$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            499.2 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +498.9 GB   disk1
                             Logical Volume on disk0s2
                             4BEE21E5-501F-4031-ADB7-FA32F0EB4C33
                             Unencrypted
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
2:       Microsoft Basic Data SANGRAH                 2.0 TB     disk2s2
```

The disk name is 'Sangrah' - that means its connected but not mounted. So, I tried mounting it but it shows a time-out error:

```
Amits-MacBook-Pro:~ amit1235813$ diskutil mount /dev/disk2s2
Volume on disk2s2 timed out waiting to mount
```

It was working fine half an hour back and now its not. Could anybody please help? Thank you!

Comment: Try "sudo diskutil umount /dev/disk2" followed by "sudo diskutil mount /dev/disk2" (don't specify s2 partition). Also, is the format NTFS, FAT, or ExFAT? Please post results.

Comment: Its weird, its mounting now without any issues. This happened last month too. In any case, I will be sure to try what you suggested the next time this issue occurs, which I am afraid it will.